# Django. OneToOneField. Reverse relation by related_name raise AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have model

```
class ClientBid(models.Model):
    bid = models.OneToOneField(Bid, verbose_name=_('Bid'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_bid')
    ...
```

When I do the next, I am getting error:

```
bid = Bid.objects.first()
bid.client_bid  # or bid.clientbid, does not matter
...
AttributeError: 'Bid' object has no attribute 'client_bid'
```

Buuuut, when I do something like that:

```
ClientBid.objects.all()
bid = Bid.objects.first()
bid.client_bid
<ClientBid: ClientBid object (1)>
```

All works fine.

Why? and how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you add the app where you defined `ClientBid` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, I did.
Also it works fine when I just import `ClientBid` model into a file where I call `bid.client_bid`
even without using it